# Wkhtmltopdf and Bootstrap - get error/exception

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

I have simple example of textarea with Bootstrap class : http://jsfiddle.net/fseokvut/

This example i save as html and try to render pdf using wkhtmltopdf

As result i get error/exception (don't know what it is exactly) :

> QImage : out of memory, returning null

on step of Printing pages. As result i get 20 pages instead of 1 (one textarea expanded on 20 pages)

My html page :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TextArea</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <div class="row-fluid col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <textarea placeholder="Type, paste, cut text here..." cols="60" class="ClstxtareaPrint form-control">PRELOADED TEXT.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
            Nam ornare elementum sapien sit amet vestibulum. 
            Maecenas et convallis lacus. 
            Etiam maximus justo quis lorem finibus sollicitudin.
            Nulla eu risus nec tellus sollicitudin finibus id blandit urna.
            Pellentesque dictum et odio sed laoreet.
        </textarea>
            </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function h(e) {
                $(e).css({'height':'auto','overflow-y':'hidden'}).height(e.scrollHeight);
            }
            $('textarea').each(function () {
              h(this);
            }).on('input', function () {
              h(this);
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

cmd command : `wkhtmltopdf.exe --javascript-delay 1000 textarea.html test2015.pdf`

---

Why i think it's Bootstrap - because i try to render pdf without class `form-control` and it works as i expected

---

**UPDATE** : as i notice, one reason why textarea is so big it's that Bootstrap set width:100% for form-control that i add as class to textArea.

I make small work-around. I add class with css rules :

width: auto !important;
min-width: 100% !important;
and textArea became smaller, but it's still bigger that must be, but just for 1 page :D

So i think problem in css styles. But what exactly i don't know.

---

**UPDATE** : yeah, problem is in width. Don't know why, but if width of textarea is bigger than max-width of pdf page (in my case format of A4) then pdf makes textarea increase it's height. So possible solution is to add js script which set size of textarea into wkhtmltopdf process. From [this link](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qprinter.html#PaperSize-enum) i get size of A4 page and set width to textarea.

Comment: Can you show this example of setting the text area please?

Comment: @Ben, well, I'd set style for textarea using `wkhtmltopdf.exe  --run-script <js> ` , where `<js>` is script of setting style for `textarea`